# Serializing elasticsearch queries using springframework elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an application where I'm using `springframework's elasticsearch`: `org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:1.0.0.RELEASE` For debugging, I want to log the queries fired to `elasticsearch` but I couldn't find any API which I could use to serialize a `CriteriaQuery` Is there any way to accomplish this? Or any setting to be enabled in elasticsearch before starting it so that it logs all queries (like mysql logging) ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest option is to configure slow logging to log every query that takes longer than 1 ms? You can find the way to do it in the elasticsearch.yml file. More information here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html